# Unity : How to get GameObject(instantiated by Prefab)'s value in while loop? GetComponent Return 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

TEST.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MeshRenderer renderer;
    public Vector3 Measurement;

    public float Length; 
    public float Width;
    public float Height; 
    public float Volume;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() 
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        Measurement = renderer.bounds.size;
        Length = Measurement.x;
        Width = Measurement.z;
        Height = Measurement.y;
        Volume = Length * Width * Height;
    }

}
```

Calculate.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

public class Calculate : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public GameObject[] Prefabs;
    [HideInInspector] public float SumOfVolume;
    [HideInInspector] public Vector3 CuboidSize;
    [HideInInspector] public float CLI;          // Cuboid Length
    [HideInInspector] public float CWI;          // Cuboid Width
    [HideInInspector] public float CHI;          // Cuboid Height


   public void MakeButtonClick()
    {  
       SumOfVolume = 0;
       CuboidSize = new Vector3(CLI, CHI, CWI);
       Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
       while (count < 4)
        {
            count++;
            if (count > 99)
                throw new System.Exception("Infinite Loop OR Failed to Create");

            GameObject clone = Instantiate(Prefabs[0], Vector3.zero, rotation);

            clone.transform.localScale = CuboidSize;
        
**            // Problem : Debug.Log(SumOfVolume ) Return 0**
              float SumOfVolume = clone.GetComponent<TEST>().Volume;
            Debug.Log(SumOfVolume);
         }         

    }
}
```

Problem : Debug.Log(SumOfVolume) Return 0
Debug.Log() outputs a value of 0 for the number of times a while statement has been turned

I guess Unity gameObject's lifecycle is the key of this problem.
Because after all clone GameObject is made, I get clone's value by GameObject.FidGameObjectsWithTag("CUBE");
I use prefab "Cube" for Instantiating clone gameObject. (Maybe one of cause)

I want to get clone's value in while loop to use it.

1. In TEST.cs, void Start -> void Awake. In this case, I can't get gameobject's Value. (even after all of gameObject was made). That return specific Value (The Value is not answer of Input Field's value)
2. In TEST.cs, void Start -> void OnEnable. Same Conclusion

Comment: `Test` and `TEST` are not the same thing. Are you sure this even compiles? I don't see `count` declared anywhere and `TEST` probably isn't a valid type.

Comment: I think I made a rudimentary mistake. I modity the point(TEST, add public int count), and there is the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the mentioned `TEST` vs `Test` (typo?)

this line

```
float SumOfVolume = clone.GetComponent<TEST>().Volume;
```

creates a local variable only existing within this iteration of the `while` loop.

Remove the `float` in order to actually use the class field `SumOfVolume`!

Further you probably wanted to actually sum them up so it should be

```
SumOfVolume += clone.GetComponent<TEST>().Volume;
```

---

Now to the actual issue - Execution Order!: `Start` is **not** called immediately after `Instantiate`! It is actually delayed until the end of this `Update` call! (My guess is they did this so you can instantiate an object and tweak some fields before `Start` initializes it fully.)

So you want to use `Awake` instead which is called right away

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Already assign this via the Inspector in your prefab
    [SerializeField] private MeshRenderer renderer;
    public Vector3 Measurement;

    public float Length; 
    public float Width;
    public float Height; 
    public float Volume;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake() 
    {
        if(!renderer) renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        Measurement = renderer.bounds.size;
        Length = Measurement.x;
        Width = Measurement.z;
        Height = Measurement.y;
        Volume = Length * Width * Height;
    }
}
```

I always stick to this as a general thumb rule:

- Use `Awake` for **everything** where you do not rely on others. Fully initialize yourself if possible
- Use `Start` only where you need others to be initialized already